# webgl library for CAD like applications

Tags: webgl, cad

I would like to create a few simple CAD like applications (web based, ideally portable to mobile devices).
For example create a floor tile layout in 2D. There is a need to enter precise measurements (floor dimensions, tile dimensions), create a layout grid from the tiles, move the tile layout around the floor etc.
Once done with the layout it would be nice to render it in 3D with texture.
Learning 2D/3D programming represents a fairly steep learning curve for me (judging from the three.js tutorials i've seen) so I would like to start with the one best suited for the task.

Comment: three.js is a good webgl framework. You might want to invest energy into learning 3D programming in general while learning a webgl framework. If you don't understand the motivation, then it makes it harder to understand  learn the framework.